# Cannot find IsChecked property in WPF Checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have a WPF app with a few checkboxes. I am able to set the IsChecked property in XAML, however, when I go to set it programatically, there is no such property. From everything I read, this property (IsChecked) is how I should be setting the value.

The XAML is below:

```
<Window x:Class="FC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="FCSX Utility" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="WhiteSmoke" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="N"
              Modifiers="Control" 
              Command="ApplicationCommands.Properties" />
        <KeyBinding Key="S"
              Modifiers="Control" 
              Command="ApplicationCommands.Print" />
        <KeyBinding Key="L"
              Modifiers="Control" 
              Command="ApplicationCommands.PrintPreview" />
        <KeyBinding Key="I"
              Modifiers="Control" 
              Command="ApplicationCommands.CancelPrint" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <TabControl Name="tcTabs" SelectionChanged="tcTabs_SelectionChanged">
        <TabItem Name="tciClock" Header="Clock">
            <StackPanel Name="spClock" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0">
                <Label FontWeight="Bold">Clock</Label>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                        <Label>Start Time</Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbHour"></ComboBox>
                        <Label>:</Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbMinute"></ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                        <Label>Day Of Week</Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbClockDay"></ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Button Name="btnSetClockSystemTime" Click="btnSetClockSystemTime_Click">Set To Current System Time</Button>
                </StackPanel>


                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Name ="ckbAlarm1" FontWeight="Bold">Alarm 1</Label>
                    <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="False"></CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Name="spAlarm1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                        <Label>Start Time</Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbAlarm1StartHour"></ComboBox>
                        <Label>:</Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbAlarm1StartMinute"></ComboBox>
                        <Label>Duration</Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbAlarm1DurationHour"></ComboBox>
                        <Label>hrs</Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbAlarm1DurationMinute"></ComboBox>
                        <Label>min</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Label>Days:</Label>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm1Mon">Mon</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm1Tues">Tue</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm1Wed">Wed</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm1Thu">Thu</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm1Fri">Fri</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm1Sat">Sat</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm1Sun">Sun</CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold">Alarm 2</Label>
                    <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm2" VerticalAlignment="Center"></CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Name="spAlarm2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                        <Label>Start Time</Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbAlarm2StartHour"></ComboBox>
                        <Label>:</Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbAlarm2StartMinute"></ComboBox>
                        <Label>Duration</Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbAlarm2DurationHour"></ComboBox>
                        <Label>hrs</Label>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbAlarm2DurationMinute"></ComboBox>
                        <Label>min</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Label>Days:</Label>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm2Mon">Mon</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm2Tues">Tue</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm2Wed">Wed</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm2Thu">Thu</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm2Fri">Fri</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm2Sat">Sat</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbAlarm2Sun">Sun</CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button>Apply</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="tciTrigger" Header="Triggering">
            <StackPanel Name="spTrigger" Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold">Trigger Options</Label>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10">
                        <Label>Reset Delay</Label>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
                            <Label>ms</Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Label>Arm Delay</Label>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
                            <Label>ms</Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Label>Take Delay A</Label>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
                            <Label>ms</Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Label>Take Delay B</Label>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
                            <Label>ms</Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold">Trigger Sources</Label>
                    <CheckBox>Internal Motion Sensor</CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox>External Sensor</CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold">Pre-Trigger Options</Label>
                    <CheckBox>Enable Pre-Trigger</CheckBox>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10">
                        <RadioButton>Pre-Trigger on Internal</RadioButton> 
                        <RadioButton>Pre-Trigger on External</RadioButton>
                        <Label>Pre-Tigger Reset Time</Label>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
                            <Label>ms</Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="tciDebug" Header="Debug" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                <Label>Command Line Output</Label>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="FW Update">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                <TextBlock Margin="5" FontSize="14">Welcome!</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="5" FontSize="14">This utility is used to update the firmware of your FC device.</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="5" FontSize="14">Please follow the steps below:</TextBlock>
                <Border Margin="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,10,10,10" Background="White">

                        <Image Name="imgUpdate" Source="/FC-Update;component/Update.png" Width="450" Margin="10" Visibility="Visible" />
                        <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,15,0" Name="lblStep1">Step 1: Connect your FC to the USB port and place<LineBreak/> the jumper in the right position.</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Name="lblStep1Done" Visibility="Collapsed">[DEVICE DETECTED]</TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,15,0" Name="lblStep2">Step 2: Power off the FCand power it back on.<LineBreak/>You should NOT hear any tones but the LED should be lit.<LineBreak/>When done click the 'Continue' button -></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Name="lblStep2Done" Visibility="Collapsed">[DONE]</TextBlock>
                            <Button Name="btnStep2Continue" Click="btnStep2Continue_Click" Visibility="Hidden" Padding="10,2,10,2" Height="30">Continue</Button>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Name="lblStep3">
                        Step 3: Click 'Choose Firmware Update...', then navigate to the provided .bin firmware update file.<LineBreak/>
                        After you select the file and click 'Open', the update will start automatically.
                        </TextBlock>

                        <Button Name="btnGo" Width="200" Height="30" Margin="10,10,10,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" Click="btnGo_Click">Choose Firmware Update...</Button>
                        <TextBlock Name="lblConnect" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible">The 'Choose Firmware Update...' button will only be enabled when<LineBreak/> your FC is connected via the USB cable and has been reset.</TextBlock>

                        <TextBlock Name="lblPleaseWait" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="OrangeRed" FontWeight="Bold">Please wait...</TextBlock>
                        <ProgressBar Name="prgMain" Width="200" Height="25" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"></ProgressBar>
                        <TextBlock Name="lblResetWait" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Green">The firmware update was downloaded and your device was reset.<LineBreak/>Please keep this window open as we wait to make sure it re-connects...</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Name="lblSuccess" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Green">The firmware update was successful and your device re-connected!<LineBreak/>Please complete Step 4 and then close this window.</TextBlock>

                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Name="lblStep4">
                    Step 4: Once the update completes successfully,<LineBreak/>remove the jumper and unplug the USB cable.
                        </TextBlock>

                        <TextBlock Name="lblError" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Red">The firmware update was NOT successful.</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Name="lblErrorMessage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Red" />

                        <Image Name="imgNoUpdate" Source="/FC-Update;component/NoUpdate.png" Width="450" Margin="10" Visibility="Collapsed" />

                        <TextBlock Name="lblAllowLuminary" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Red" Foreground="White" Margin="10">Will Allow Luminary EPT Devices. Press Ctrl-L Again to Disallow.</TextBlock>

                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>

            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

```html
if (Regex.Matches(alarm1Data.ToString(), "ALARM 1 DISABLED").Count == 1)
{
   spAlarm1.IsEnabled = false;
   // ckbAlarm1.IsChecked = false; // <--- property not found
}
```

Comment: show us your code ??

Comment: Maybe the object you're using is of some different type (`Object` for instance?) and you need to cast it to `CheckBox` first... Just guessing.

Comment: posting some code will get you there :) .. don't keep us guessing

Comment: I just tried and I could do it. Can you post your XAML and code?

Comment: you like people wasting their time don't you.. :))

Comment: Is that snippet from a "code behind" file of that page?

What if you try `((CheckBox)ckbAlarm1).IsChecked` ?

Comment: If I understand what you mean by "code behind"... yes. Mainwindow.xaml and Mainwindow.xaml.cs

Comment: this is simplest case imho, try restarting vs

Comment: Hmmm... I get an error that says can't convert System.Windows.Controls.Label to System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox. I  don't understand why? My XAML is pretty straigt forward no?

Comment: you haven't posted us all the  code then have you ?

Comment: Weird, something somewhere must be messing with your controls 0_o
What if you add another checkbox someplace else in the XAML, outside of that `StackPanel` - will its `IsChecked` property be available then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Label Name ="ckbAlarm1" FontWeight="Bold">Alarm 1</Label>
```

ckbAlarm1 is a LABEL !!

Comment: Embarrassed.... I read the error... looked at it several more times and read what I wanted to read. Sorry and thank you!

Comment: That's cool Jason we all have been in this position many times :P

Comment: @Muds - I was just about to comment with a "D'oh!"... and then I saw your avatar ;D

Comment: @Jason - no wonder we were so stupified. In the short XAML snippet you had posted before this long one the name was assigned to the `CheckBox`... So how the hell would that object be a Label? ;D

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express and had the same problem, but with a different solution. The correct code for this platform is:

```
this.checkBoxDebugMode.Checked = World.Setup.Debug;
```

instead of

```
this.checkBoxDebugMode.IsChecked = World.Setup.Debug;
```

`IsChecked` is not a valid property here, but it's what you find when you look it up.

Comment: Please use the code tags (ctrl + k) to format your code sections.